# Access wordpress custom plugin from site

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a small plugin I'm accessing it both admin and users from the dashboard.

This is my code:

```
function directory_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("Contacts Directory", "Contacts Directory", 1, "Contacts_directory", "directory_admin");  
}
```

I want to access this from the front-end site(Eg : in a page). I don't know how to do it. Please give any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by access from front-end site . This function works on WP admin.

Comment: Can you explain your question.

Comment: Yes, I created a plugin It shows a form and takes input from the user and saves in DB. Now I'm accessing it from settings tab in dashboard. I want to access this form in home page or some thing other page.